# Why do my Arrow Keys stop working and the cursor just jump from button to button?

Tags: vb.net, keydown, arrow-keys

I am working on an app to do quality review of scanned books. I display two pages at a time and let the user use the arrow keys or on-screen buttons to move right or left. The arrow keys work fine until one of arrow buttons is clicked. Then the cursor just jumps from button to button.

### Capturing keystrokes:

```
    Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) _
  Handles Me.KeyDown
    If (e.KeyCode = Keys.Right) And (currStatus <> "LastPage") Then
        Call MoveRight()
    End If
    If (e.KeyCode = Keys.Left) And (currStatus <> "FirstPage") Then
        Call MoveLeft()
    End If
End Sub
```

### Buttons on each side:

I found and tried "Me.KeyPreview = True" but it made no difference.
I even tried adding coding .KeyDown for each of the buttons but it made no difference.

Comment: [PreviewKeyDownEventArgs.IsInputKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.previewkeydowneventargs.isinputkey)

Comment: The info on this page explains KeyDowns, Forms and Controls: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keydown?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Comment: Got it working by adding this to all 14 buttons:
Private Sub {button}_PreviewKeyDown(sender As Object, e As PreviewKeyDownEventArgs)  Handles {button}.PreviewKeyDown
        e.IsInputKey = True
    End Sub

Controls/buttons normally do not treat Arrow Keys as InputKeys. But you can use this technique to make them work like InputKeys.